# C++ template class as argument of a function

Tags: c++, templates, arduino

There is a class library (I cannot/should not change) defined in MIDI.h:

```
template<class SerialPort, class _Settings = DefaultSettings>
class MidiInterface
{
      ...
```

I want to use this class as argument. 
Question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661347/passing-template-class-as-parameter) is a duplicate, however I still get a compilation error.

My own header class file looks like:

```
#include <MIDI.h>

class M
{
  public:
    void setup();
    void run();

  private:
    void printMessage(const MidiInterface<SerialPort, _Settings>&
          midiInterface);
};
```

I get the following errors:

In file included from sketch\M.cpp:1:0:

```
M.h:10: error: 'MidiInterface' does not name a type

 void printMessage(const MidiInterface<SerialPort, _Settings>& midiInterface);

                         ^

M.h:10: error: expected ',' or '...' before '<' token

 void printMessage(const MidiInterface<SerialPort, _Settings>& midiInterface);

                                      ^

exit status 1
'MidiInterface' does not name a type
```

How can I change the code so it compiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like MIDI.h in [this code](https://github.com/FortySevenEffects/arduino_midi_library/tree/master/src) puts everything in a namespace.  If that's what you're using, try `MIDI_NAMESPACE::MidiInterface<SerialPort, _Settings>`.

Comment: Upvote +1, because finding the original source was really slick

Comment: @aschepler: I updated my question after you put your answer, I didn't even mention Arduino, still you found it.

It now works (with your help), I also had to change a bit more (like settings and serialport, but it compiles, thanks to your answer and pointing the way).