# Is it possible to define a non-template function that can take a templated object as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am using a C++ class which is templated.

I instantiate two different templated version of this class:

```
ExampleClass<ParamType1> obj1;
ExampleClass<ParamType2> obj2;
```

So that I have two objects which are the same class, but with different template parameters.

I now want to be able to define a function (extremely simplified example!) that can take either obj1 or obj2 as a parameter:

```
int func(ExampleClassXXX obj_param)
{
  return obj_param.member_operation();
}
```

So that I can call either `func(obj1)` or `func(obj2`.

Is this something that is possible, and if so, what is the syntax needed for the function definition to specify the `obj_param` parameter is "an instance of ExampleClass created with any template parameters"?

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661347/passing-template-class-as-parameter) sort of covers the case that is one step more general - having "obj_param" be any type. Most of the details are missing from the text of that answer, it is only when you click on the "live demo" that you see they are instantiating a templated `struct` to be able to pass in the generic parameter, which is pretty ugly.

It seems like this should be a common thing to want to do, but Googling has failed me so far (searching for "passing templated object as function parameter")

Comment: *"So that I have two objects which are the same class, but with different template parameters."* - `obj1` and `obj2` are objects of different, unrelated classes. `func` needs to be a template as well, like `template<typename x_Param> int func(ExampleClass<x_Param> obj_param)`

Comment: Make the function a template function, or declare a base class and take that as an argument

Comment: `ExampleClass` is the template, `ExampleClass<ParamType1>` is the class.

Answer (score 6):

Note that

```
ExampleClass<ParamType1>
```

and

```
ExampleClass<ParamType2>
```

are basically two different classes for the language.

You have two possibilities, in my opinion, the first being:

```
template<typename ParamType>
int func(ExampleClass<ParamType> obj_param){}
```

The second possibility is to give to `ExampleClass` a non-templated public base class (basically implementing type erasure) like so

```
 template<typename T>
 class ExampleClass : public ExampleClassBase{};
```

and then re-write the function as

```
int func(ExampleClassBase& obj_param){}
```

but you will not be able to pass by value in this case because of object slicing issues.

The template function forces you to implement the function in a header file if you want to keep it as general as possible, the non-templated base class forces you to pay for virtual function call.

Edit: as per Alan Birtles comment, if you know already all the types you will instantiate `ExampleClass` with you can implement each version of the function in a cpp file.

Comment: "The templated function forces you to implement the function in a header file" not, necessarily, you can provide the implementations for each class in a cpp file and just declare the function in the header

Comment: @AlanBirtles I was unsure whether to add it to the description, it is a good point, but I felt that it could have been too much info. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> So that I have two objects which are the same class, but with different template parameters.

A contradiction right there. If the arguments are different, this is not the same class. A template is not a class, it's a mold. If you pour two different metals into it, you'd get two very different objects, despite the similar shape. They'd have different mass and density, possibly different electromagnetic properties, and so forth. A bit tangential, but it's important to differentiate the template from the things it produces, those are not the same.

This is why different specializations produced from the same template are considered different classes. They are not related under the type system, and so no function can automatically treat them as the same thing. You could create a function template, and use it to generate functions for each distinct specialization, but those too would be different functions.

If you have a part that's common to all specializations, you could refactor it out into a  base class (proper class, not a class template), and have a function that accepts *that*.

Comment: While true, your answer doesn't really answer OP's question. I understand that OP has a contradiction, but the fundamental problem is clear.

Comment: @Neijwiert - Could have sworn I wrote a bit at the end about a common base class.